# Wordpress custom permalinks not working on OS X localhost

Tags: wp-admin, options, localhost

When changing premalinks, none of the pages and links are not working except home page :(

[image]

Result are shown below. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Enable `mod_rewrite`. You can see by the error message that the server did not send the request to WordPress.

Comment: @toscho how can I do that ?

Comment: Depends on your server and how you have set up the localhost. Look up the server docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really a server question and not specific to WordPress.

Be sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled in `httpd.conf` Apache on your version of OS X. (Google that with your version of OS X.) Restart Apache after making changes to httpd.conf.

You may also need to add a blank .htaccess file in the /Users/yourusername/Sites folder so the file has the correct permissions and so WordPress can write to it from the Settings >> Permalinks screen in admin. And to do that, you will need to add the .htaccess file in Terminal, as OS X hides unix "invisible" files - files with a leading . - in the finder.