# cannot access subsites in wordpress multisite

Tags: multisite, customization, multi-language

Hi I installed wordpress multisite using instructions given on codex and created a site. But I cannot access any other than base site.

As you can see in the screenshot below multisite is installed and I have created multilang/de/ but it is not accessible. 
[image]

Comment: That's because you're running local. See [this thread](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73906/wordpress-custom-permalinks-not-working-on-os-x-localhost) to enable permalink on localhost

Comment: Thanks JMau. that thread did not solve the problem but this thread did.http://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache . It has some additional settings